# Where is the Dokan Library documentation?

Tags: dokan

I'm using Dokan 0.6.0 but the Dokan websites don't give any documentation. Does anyone know where I can get documentation for the Dokan library.

Comment: Dokan website -> Getting Help (in top navbar) -> Wiki: https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/wiki

Comment: [Home · dokan-dev/dokany Wiki](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/wiki)

Comment: Are there any sample Dokan drivers>

Comment: @user215779 Scroll the homepage down, there's a list of open-source stuff implemented with Dokan.